# Why is AppScale based on virtual machines?

Tags: appscale

I try to understand the basics of [AppScale](http://www.appscale.com/), more specifically why it [apparently relies](http://www.appscale.com/get-started) on being installed on a *virtual machine*.

Three questions:

1. Why is AppScale not "just" a conventional package (for example a .deb package), just like most other software?
2. There exists an "install from source" option on the download page. Why does that also require the installation target to be a *virtual* machine? And how can it tell if it really is?
3. Does this virtual machine requirement imply that AppScale can only be used on hosting centers that allows me to upload my own images, e.g. the ones provided on the AppScale download page? The "install from source" option suggests that it is not so - but couldn't I then install AppScale if I had a dedicated machine on my hosting center?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AppScale does not require you to use a VM, but suggests you do for simplicity (just download the image instead of having to build one). You can install AppScale directly on the physical machine if you choose to do so.

Comment: OK, so it is not a *requirement* as such, even though their documentation never mentions non-virtual install targets? But then I don't get why there is no conventional install package. Are there any particular reasons why I cannot just perform an "apt-get appscale", the debian way?

Comment: We had this some years back, but we stopped maintaining it. We didn't see too much of a gain in terms of ease-of-use between running the apt-get command and running our bootstrap script. We may bring back debian packaging in the future if the demand is high enough.